# Is the code properly refactored or still some more improvements needs to be done?

Tags: java

I have got code here which I have tried to refactor on my own - but do any of you experts feel that it needs to be refactored more? What are the points should I cover? I would appreciate it if some one gives me some points on this code review.

```
package com.vilant.app.outbound;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import com.vilant.app.db.Container;
import com.vilant.app.db.OutboundQueue;
import com.vilant.app.db.Shipment;
import com.vilant.util.jpa.EntityManagerController;
import com.vilant.util.jpa.ThreadLocalEntityManager;

/* TODO: responsibility resolvation through database is far from bulletproof... */


// TODO: implement HA negotiation and failover + message passing to active sender
public class OutboundSender implements Runnable {

    private org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    // minutes after next attempt time when to acquire queue item from db
    private int acquireThreshold = 120; // TODO: make configurable

    // database orphaned queue item check interval
    private int dbCheckInterval = 120; // TODO: make configurable

    private Date nextDbCheck = new Date();

    private ThreadLocalEntityManager tem;
    private EntityManagerController emc;


    private List<OutboundHandler> attemptQueue = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<OutboundHandler>());
    private Thread runnerThread;
    private OutboundSender runner;
    private boolean running = true;


    private static OutboundSender instance;
    private OutboundSender() {

    }
    public void initPersistence(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        tem = new ThreadLocalEntityManager(emf);
        emc = new EntityManagerController(tem);
    }

    public static OutboundSender getInstance() {
        synchronized(OutboundSender.class) {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = new OutboundSender();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }


    private void enqueueContainerRelatedMessage(Container container, Class<? extends OutboundHandler> senderClass, String parameter, Long queueId, long acquiredWith, int attempts) throws Exception {
        OutboundHandler handler = null;
        handler = senderClass.newInstance();
        handler.setPersistenceObjects(tem, emc);
        handler.setAcquiredValue(acquiredWith);
        handler.setAttempts(attempts);
        handler.prepareContainer(container, parameter);
        handler.setQueueId(queueId);
        handler.init();
        attemptQueue.add(handler);
        runnerThread.interrupt();
    }

    public void sendContainerRelatedMessage(Container container, Class<? extends OutboundHandler> senderClass, String parameter) throws Exception {
        this.sendContainerRelatedMessage(container, senderClass, parameter, false);
    }
    // TODO: implement others, move persistence stuff to a service class
    public void sendContainerRelatedMessage(Container container, Class<? extends OutboundHandler> senderClass, String parameter, boolean startAsIdle) throws Exception {
        if (container.getId()==null) throw new IllegalStateException("Container ID not set");
        Long queueId = null;
        long acquireValue = (long)(Math.random()*Long.MAX_VALUE);
        try {
            emc.beginTx();
            Query query = tem.createQuery("SELECT oq FROM OutboundQueue oq WHERE oq.idType = :idType AND oq.idValue = :idValue AND oq.senderClass = :senderClass AND oq.parameter = :parameter AND oq.sent IS NULL");
            query.setParameter("idType", OutboundQueue.IdentifierType.CONTAINER_ID);
            query.setParameter("idValue", container.getId());
            query.setParameter("senderClass", senderClass.getCanonicalName());
            query.setParameter("parameter", parameter);
            List<OutboundQueue> queueList = query.getResultList();
            OutboundQueue queue = null;
            if (queueList.size()==0) {
                queue = new OutboundQueue();
                queue.setIdType(OutboundQueue.IdentifierType.CONTAINER_ID);
                queue.setIdValue(container.getId());
                queue.setParameter(parameter);
                queue.setSenderClass(senderClass.getCanonicalName());
                queue.setHandler(acquireValue);
                queue.setShipmentId(container.getShipment().getId());
                queue.setIdle(startAsIdle);
                tem.persist(queue);
            }
            else {
                if (queueList.size()>1){
                    log.warn("Multiple outbound handlers with the same parameters. Should not happen.");
                }
                queue = queueList.get(0);
            }
            queue.setIdle(startAsIdle);
            queue.setAttempts(0);
            tem.merge(queue);

            if ((queueId = queue.getId())==null) throw new IllegalStateException("Queue ID is null.");

            emc.commitTx();
        }
        finally {
            if (!startAsIdle) this.enqueueContainerRelatedMessage(container, senderClass, parameter, queueId, acquireValue, 0);
            emc.closeEm();
        }
    }


    private void enqueueShipmentRelatedMessage(Shipment shipment, Class<? extends OutboundHandler> senderClass, String parameter, Long queueId, long acquiredWith, int attempts) throws Exception {
        OutboundHandler handler = null;
        handler = senderClass.newInstance();
        handler.setPersistenceObjects(tem, emc);
        handler.setAcquiredValue(acquiredWith);
        handler.prepareShipment(shipment, parameter);
        handler.setQueueId(queueId);
        handler.setAttempts(attempts);
        handler.init();
        attemptQueue.add(handler);
        runnerThread.interrupt();
    }

    public void sendShipmentRelatedMessage(Shipment shipment, Class<? extends OutboundHandler> senderClass, String parameter) throws Exception {
        this.sendShipmentRelatedMessage(shipment, senderClass, parameter, false);
    }
    public void sendShipmentRelatedMessage(Shipment shipment, Class<? extends OutboundHandler> senderClass, String parameter, boolean startAsIdle) throws Exception {
        Long queueId = null;
        long acquireValue = (long)(Math.random()*Long.MAX_VALUE);
        try {
            emc.beginTx();
            Query query = tem.createQuery("SELECT oq FROM OutboundQueue oq WHERE oq.idType = :idType AND oq.idValue = :idValue AND oq.senderClass = :senderClass AND oq.parameter = :parameter AND oq.sent IS NULL");
            query.setParameter("idType", OutboundQueue.IdentifierType.SHIPMENT_ID);
            query.setParameter("idValue", shipment.getId());
            query.setParameter("senderClass", senderClass.getCanonicalName());
            query.setParameter("parameter", parameter);
            List<OutboundQueue> queueList = query.getResultList();
            OutboundQueue queue = null;
            if (queueList.size()==0) {
                queue = new OutboundQueue();
                queue.setIdType(OutboundQueue.IdentifierType.SHIPMENT_ID);
                queue.setIdValue(shipment.getId());
                queue.setParameter(parameter);
                queue.setSenderClass(senderClass.getCanonicalName());
                queue.setHandler(acquireValue);
                queue.setShipmentId(shipment.getId());
                queue.setIdle(startAsIdle);
                tem.persist(queue);
            }
            else {
                if (queueList.size()>1){
                    log.warn("Multiple outbound handlers with the same parameters. Should not happen.");
                }
                queue = queueList.get(0);
            }
            queue.setIdle(startAsIdle);
            queue.setAttempts(0);
            tem.merge(queue);

            if ((queueId = queue.getId())==null) throw new IllegalStateException("Queue ID is null.");

            emc.commitTx();
        }
        finally {
            if (!startAsIdle) this.enqueueShipmentRelatedMessage(shipment, senderClass, parameter, queueId, acquireValue, 0);
            emc.closeEm();
        }
    }

    // TODO: refresh queue from database
    public void run() {
        while (running) {

            // update queue if needed
            if (new Date().after(nextDbCheck)) {
                this.performDbCheck();
                this.nextDbCheck = new Date(new Date().getTime()+1000*dbCheckInterval);
            }

            // sort queue (by time)
            Collections.sort(attemptQueue);

            // for all items with their resend time passed, attempt a send
            while (!attemptQueue.isEmpty() && attemptQueue.get(0).getNextAttemptTime().before(new Date())) {
                try {
                    OutboundQueue q = null;
                    try {
                        q = tem.find(OutboundQueue.class, attemptQueue.get(0).getQueueId());
                        System.out.println(q.getHandler() + " vs " + attemptQueue.get(0).getAcquiredValue());
                        if (q.getHandler()!=attemptQueue.get(0).getAcquiredValue()) {
                            log.info("Another handler has acquired queue item with id {}, ", q.getId());
                            attemptQueue.remove(0);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("Database not accessible for persistent queue handling");
                    }
                    attemptQueue.get(0).sendAndRefreshNextAttempt();
                    OutboundHandler handler = attemptQueue.remove(0);
                    if (q!=null) try {
                        emc.beginTx();
                        log.info("Message delivered, marking sent in DB.");
                        q.setSent(new java.util.Date());
                        q.setAttempts(handler.getAttempts());
                        q.setNextAttempt(handler.getNextAttemptTime());
                        q.setIdle(false); // probably a nop, but better safe than sorry
                        q.setHandler(handler.getAcquiredValue());
                        emc.commitTx();
                    }
                    catch (Exception f) {
                        log.error("Unable to update queue status for succeeded message", f);
                    }
                    finally {
                        // ensure never to throw exception, will result in resending after successful
                        try { emc.closeEm(); } catch (Exception ignored) {}
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    log.warn("Unable to send message", e);
                    if (attemptQueue.get(0).getNextAttemptTime()==null) {
                        // sender doesn't want to retry
                        OutboundHandler handler = attemptQueue.remove(0);
                        emc.beginTx();
                        try {
                            log.info("Could not deliver message, giving up.");
                            OutboundQueue q = tem.find(OutboundQueue.class, handler.getQueueId());
                            q.setIdle(true);
                            q.setLatestError(e.getMessage());
                            q.setAttempts(handler.getAttempts());
                            q.setNextAttempt(handler.getNextAttemptTime());
                            emc.commitTx();
                        }
                        catch (Exception f) {
                            log.error("Unable to update queue status for failed message", f);
                        }
                        finally {
                            emc.closeEm();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        OutboundHandler handler = attemptQueue.get(0);
                        emc.beginTx();
                        try {
                            log.info("Could not deliver message, updating error.");
                            OutboundQueue q = tem.find(OutboundQueue.class, handler.getQueueId());
                            q.setIdle(false);
                            q.setLatestError(e.getMessage());
                            q.setAttempts(handler.getAttempts());
                            q.setNextAttempt(handler.getNextAttemptTime());
                            q.setHandler(handler.getAcquiredValue());
                            emc.commitTx();
                        }
                        catch (Exception f) {
                            log.error("Unable to update queue error status for failed message", f);
                        }
                        finally {
                            emc.closeEm();
                        }

                    }
                    // sort queue (by time)
                    Collections.sort(attemptQueue);
                }
            }
            if (!running) break;
            // if queue contains items, sleep until resending
            long sleepAmount= Long.MAX_VALUE;
            if (!attemptQueue.isEmpty()) {
                sleepAmount = attemptQueue.get(0).getNextAttemptTime().getTime()-new Date().getTime();
            }

            long sleepBeforeDbUpdate = this.nextDbCheck.getTime() - new Date().getTime();

            if (sleepBeforeDbUpdate<sleepAmount) sleepBeforeDbUpdate = sleepAmount;

            if (sleepAmount>0L) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepAmount);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    log.trace("OutboundSender sleep interrupted");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void start() {
        OutboundSender sender = getInstance();
        runnerThread = new Thread(sender);
        runnerThread.setDaemon(true);
        runnerThread.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
        runnerThread.interrupt();
        try {
            runnerThread.join();
        }
        catch (Exception ignored) {}
    }

    private void performDbCheck() {
        Query query = tem.createQuery("SELECT oq FROM OutboundQueue oq WHERE oq.idle = :idle AND oq.sent IS NULL");
        query.setParameter("idle", Boolean.FALSE);
        List<OutboundQueue> results = query.getResultList();
        nextItem:
        for (OutboundQueue q : results) {
            try {
                Class tempClass = this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(q.getSenderClass());
                Class<OutboundHandler> handlerClass = tempClass;
                if (handlerClass!=null) {

                    for (OutboundHandler h : this.attemptQueue) {
                        if (h.getQueueId()==q.getId()) {
                            // ignore items already being handled
                            continue nextItem;
                        }
                    }
                    if (q.getNextAttempt()!=null && q.getNextAttempt().after(new Date(new Date().getTime()-1000*acquireThreshold))) {
                        log.debug("Acquire threshold not met for queue item id {}", q.getId());
                        continue;
                    }
                    // TODO: other types
                    if (q.getIdType()==OutboundQueue.IdentifierType.CONTAINER_ID) {
                        Container container = tem.find(Container.class, q.getIdValue());
                        if (container!=null) {
                            emc.beginTx();
                            long acquireValue = (long)(Math.random()*Long.MAX_VALUE);
                            q.setHandler(acquireValue);
                            tem.merge(q);
                            emc.commitTx();
                            this.enqueueContainerRelatedMessage(container, handlerClass, q.getParameter(), q.getId(), acquireValue, q.getAttempts());
                        }
                        else {
                            log.error("Container has disappeared from database, removing queue item");
                            emc.beginTx();
                            tem.merge(q);
                            tem.remove(q);
                            emc.commitTx();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (q.getIdType()==OutboundQueue.IdentifierType.SHIPMENT_ID) {
                        Shipment shipment = tem.find(Shipment.class, q.getIdValue());
                        if (shipment!=null) {
                            emc.beginTx();
                            long acquireValue = (long)(Math.random()*Long.MAX_VALUE);
                            q.setHandler(acquireValue);
                            tem.merge(q);
                            emc.commitTx();
                            this.enqueueShipmentRelatedMessage(shipment, handlerClass, q.getParameter(), q.getId(), acquireValue, q.getAttempts());
                        }
                        else {
                            log.error("Shipment has disappeared from database, removing queue item");
                            emc.beginTx();
                            tem.merge(q);
                            tem.remove(q);
                            emc.commitTx();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    log.error("Unable to prepare handler for outbound queue with id {}" + q.getId());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Unable to init queue item from database.", e);
            }
            finally {
                emc.closeEm();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it looks like this after refactoring I wonder what it looked like before :))

Comment: If you've read Uncle Bob's Clean Code book, you should remember the first rule of functions: "Functions should be small!", not to mention the second rule of functions "They should be smaller than that!".
`enqueueShipmentRelatedMessage` for instance, not only enqueues a message, but it creates one. Two responsibilities within the same function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First , It seems that this code violates Single Responsibility Principle and it way too long to do just a single task .If that's the case maybe you can introduce new small classes that assist this class in doing its task.
Second , I can see signs of DRY here and there specially in performDbCheck :

here :

```
 if (q.getIdType()==OutboundQueue.IdentifierType.CONTAINER_ID) {
                        Container container = tem.find(Container.class, q.getIdValue());
                        if (container!=null) {
                            emc.beginTx();
                            long acquireValue = (long)(Math.random()*Long.MAX_VALUE);
                            q.setHandler(acquireValue);
                            tem.merge(q);
                            emc.commitTx();
                            this.enqueueContainerRelatedMessage(container, handlerClass, q.getParameter(), q.getId(), acquireValue, q.getAttempts());
                        }
                        else {
                            log.error("Container has disappeared from database, removing queue item");
                            emc.beginTx();
                            tem.merge(q);
                            tem.remove(q);
                            emc.commitTx();
                        }
                    }
                    else if
```

You are doing the same thing in several conditions like beginTx(),tem.merge(q) and ....
and there are only a few exceptional line of codes in between. You can have a method that accept some callback function to do the general task + excpetional code:

for example :

```
public void RunTransaction(IExceptionalCode code)
{
beginTran();
merge();
code.DoTheTask();
endTran();
}
```

then you can have different classes implementing IExceptionalCode doing specific task:
3.There are a lot of nested if s in your code that make your code hard to read and maintain.You can have a Rule object that has a condition and an IExceptionalCode objct in it

```
public Rule 
{
private ICondition _condition;

private IExceptionalCode_logic;

public Rule(ICondition condition,IExceptioanlCode code)
{
_condition=conditionl
_logic=code;
}

public void Apply(parameters to be check)
{
if(_condition.IsTrue(parameters to be check) RunTransaction(_logic);
}
}
```

then you can have a list of rules in your method and :

```
foreach(Rule rule in rules)
rule.Apply(parameters);
```

This way you can add more logic to your code later very easily by introducing new rules.

Comment: thanks for the response @Beatles but what do you mean by DRY?

Comment: Don't repeat yourself :)) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself